# Rename and copy specific files by preserving the relative path in ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have several `.env.sample` files in my project directory.
And I want to copy them to the `.env` by preserving the relative path.

before

```
.env.sample
apps
  -- app
  -- .env.sample
```

after

```
.env.sample
.env
apps
  -- app
  -- .env.sample
  -- .env
```

I already tried something like this:

```bash
find . -name .env.sample -exec cp {} $(echo {} | awk -F.sample '{print $1}') \;
```

But it doesn't work. The second part of the `cp` command doesn't work as I expected. Maybe something about the escaping special character is needed.

Any command that could do the job would be appreciated. And I can learn something new about bash if someone can explain what the problem is in my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
find . -name .env.sample -execdir sh -c 'cp -- "$1" "${1%.*}"' _ {} +
```

---

- See [understanding-the-exec-option-of-find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)